# JavaScript CodeExplorer tool?

Tags: javascript, ide, editor

Where can I find an editor/IDE with the ability to display a JavaScript code explorer? There are many editors which display that for PHP files, some of them for JS as well, but so far I haven't found one which displays the class structure of the JS file. I tried parsing the "prototype" framework with PSPad, but unfortunately it doesn't display it correctly. It handles all the functions, but I want them to be shown structured in classes, like they are.

The tree should look something like this for example (code of prototype):

```
- Prototype
 * Version
 - Browser
  * IE
  * Opera
  * WebKit
  * Gecko
  * MobileSafari
 + BrowserFeatures (and it's children)
 + .. etc etc
```

For the following code:

```
var Prototype = {
  Version: '1.6.0.3',

  Browser: {
    IE:     !!(window.attachEvent &&
      navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Opera') === -1),
    Opera:  navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Opera') > -1,
    WebKit: navigator.userAgent.indexOf('AppleWebKit/') > -1,
    Gecko:  navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Gecko') > -1 &&
      navigator.userAgent.indexOf('KHTML') === -1,
    MobileSafari: !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Apple.*Mobile.*Safari/)
  },

  BrowserFeatures: {
    XPath: !!document.evaluate,
    SelectorsAPI: !!document.querySelector,
    ElementExtensions: !!window.HTMLElement,
    SpecificElementExtensions:
      document.createElement('div')['__proto__'] &&
      document.createElement('div')['__proto__'] !==
        document.createElement('form')['__proto__']
  },

  ScriptFragment: '<script[^>]*>([\\S\\s]*?)<\/script>',
  JSONFilter: /^\/\*-secure-([\s\S]*)\*\/\s*$/,

  emptyFunction: function() { },
  K: function(x) { return x }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [aptana studio](http://www.aptana.org/studio).